# Missing character: There is no (U+0020) in font [academicons.ttf]:!

Tags: xetex, fontawesome, academicons

I am trying to compile a cv-template (available on overleaf) with xetex.
My latex/xetex configuration works perfectly on every other template but this one.
Bellow I attach the final lines of the log file where the warnings and errors start.
It seems that the error roots in two packages (academicons and fontsawsome), but I do not have any clue how to correct them. (In addition the template compiles with no problem on overleaf)
I would appreciate any help to make the compile flawless:

'''

```
Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
File: PIC//Picture.jpg Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//Picture.jpg>
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+academicons on input
line 59.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/academicons/tuacademicons.fd)
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [academicons.ttf]:!
File: PIC//England.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//England.png>
File: PIC//Italy.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//Italy.png>
File: PIC//Spain.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//Spain.png>
File: PIC//France.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//France.png>
File: PIC//QR_Info.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//QR_Info.png>
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.95116pt on input line 93.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.6658pt on input line 93.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.02315pt on input line 93.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.94882pt on input line 93.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.66417pt on input line 93.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.02185pt on input line 93.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/FontAwesome(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/FontAwesome(0)/m/n' instead on input line 99.

File: PIC//Ship.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//Ship.png>
File: PIC//Jolly-Roger.png Graphic file (type bmp)
<PIC//Jolly-Roger.png>
./main.tex:119: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\aiOBP 
               } PUBLICATIONS
l.119         \section*{{\aiOBP} PUBLICATIONS}
                                          
? 
./main.tex:119: Emergency stop.
<argument> {\aiOBP 
               } PUBLICATIONS
l.119         \section*{{\aiOBP} PUBLICATIONS}
                                          
End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
43132 strings out of 476191
914383 string characters out of 5812071
1508773 words of memory out of 5000000
63144 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
471760 words of font info for 80 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
116i,18n,142p,448b,1229s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

'''

Comment: as you have shown no code it is hard to tell you what is wrong, U+0020 is a space but tex does not normally use space characters from a font. But your main error is `\aiOBP` undefined, you could define it with `\newcommand` but what do you want its definition to be?

Comment: `\aiOBP` is from `academicons`, it is an open book icon. It was added to the package on March 10, 2022, maybe your local version is older than that? Anyway, either update the package or change `\aiOBP` in your template to the definition `\AI\symbol{"E92A}`.

Comment: Thanks David and Marijn for quick responses. @Marijn response made the compilation successful but the result .pdf is distorted !

Comment: Distorted how exactly? You do need to keep the braces that were around `\aiOBP`, so `\section*{{\AI\symbol{"E92A}}PUBLICATIONS}`, otherwise the font change will affect the word _PUBLICATIONS_ as well.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn There was actually no problem. I had to compile two times. Now the result is perfect.